# Drupal: multilanguage.. looking for the right module to build multiple versions of the node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a multi-language website.

I want a module to add multiple version of my nodes and selecting the right one for each language of my website.

In other terms, for each node, I want to have more versions, a version for each language. I don't want to create new nodes, in order to avoid confusion for my customer.

I want to be able to fill the content for each language version of the same node.

If I'm not wrong, the core module Content Translation allows me to select for each node to which language interface belongs to, which is not what I want.

I saw the internationalization module, and it is good for translating taxonomy terms, and blocks, but it doesn't provide the functionality I want (multiple versions of each node).

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal.org has a lot of documentation related to multilingual sites.
http://drupal.org/node/324602

You may find that the [Internationalization module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) will help you out. See this [tutorial](http://www.isegura.es/blog/drupal-multiple-languages-part-one-core-configuration) on setting up multilingual site using the Internationalization module.

Comment: yeah it has tons of documentation pages about it, it is a bit disorienting and I'm actually inspecting the international module right now, but I cannot find such functionality. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks for the Tutorial, it is exactly the answer to my question. However I was wondering if I can use CCK translation module (in internalizational module) instead of modifying the template (as suggested in the third page of the tutorial). What is CCK Translation module doing exactly ? Is maybe adding a selectable language for each CCK field ?

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick: CCK Translation makes it possible to have the labels and description of your CCK fields translated to different languages. The content that's stored inside those fields gets translated for the entire node, including all its fields using i18n module.

Comment: mhm, 2 questions: 1) can I fill the labels for each language, or is this done automatically ? 2) So.. same questions, can I fill the content of CCK Field for each node, from the same page ? (I want to keep a single node for all language versions, in order to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 0):

Hey! Thanks for reading my tutorial.

To properly translate CCK labels:

1 - activate CCK Translation module

2 - write the labels for your CCK fields in **english**

3 - Go to the "create new node" page. You're doing this to force Drupal to use the labels you just created. Visit the "create node" page in all your languages, so you force Drupal to try to show you the label in all the languages you have configured.

I know, this step is weird.

4 - Go to Admin -> Translate Interface (/admin/build/translate). Click on "search". Search your label in **english**, you'll see it appears several times, but marked as untranslated. Click on 'edit' for every string and translate them.

A bit clunky, but it works.