# drupal Multi language in single node

Tags: drupal-6

i am trying to get into the drupal 6 Multilanguage support.

i am trying to do it using the [i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118917/drupal-multilanguage-looking-for-the-right-module-to-build-multiple-versions-o)  module.
from what i understood so far, the Internationalization lets me translate node/taxonomy/menus/blocks into any other language defined in my Locale languages setting.

but the main draw back in the module behavior, is that as far as i understand, each translation becomes a new node/taxonomy/menus.
such behavior causes my multi language site to behave not as a mirror site.

for example:

1. http://mysite/en/node/5 sends me to the english version of node 5. but http://mysite/he/node/5 wont send me to the hebrew translation of node 5, cause the hebrew translation of node 5 is not node number 5, but number 7, so instead of getting translated hebrew node, i will get 404 error page.

i can think of many other problems that will have to be dealt due to this multiple nodes.

i am looking for a way to translate my node/taxonomy/block/menu in a way that wont duplicate nodes but save all the translation in the same node. when i think about it, it doesnt seems that complicated to implement, so i am pretty sure that there are such modules out there, i just havent found them yet... any idea ?
a similar question can be found at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118917/drupal-multilanguage-looking-for-the-right-module-to-build-multiple-versions-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the method for creating a multilingual page in Drupal is such that it will create a new node for each translation. Same for menus and taxonomy.

I'm not sure Drupal can do an exact mirror of a site. As I understand and have experienced, multiligual in Drupal is best thought of as running multiple sites (one per each language), on the same site. So it's not quite as simple as having an English site and then a mirror of it in another language. You have to create both.

Comment: thanks lordg. i have looked into the subject, and you are correct in your way of understanding. but only for drupal 6. on drupal 7, came the field api wich supports multi language per field.. meaning that it is possible to maintain a single node with X fields in Y languages.